# Alamofire : Updating array's values with JSON's data

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I have a problem when trying to update an array of struct with the JSON's data. Here's my code:

This is how the struct is defined:
[Struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTlx0.png)

```
struct Shot {
    var title: String
    var desc: String
    var img: String

    init(title: String, desc: String, img: String) {
      self.title = title
      self.desc = desc
      self.img = img
    }
  }
```

Here I try to update the array, but it doesn't work:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLAXs.png)

```
  func authDribbble() {
    let endURL = "https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots/"
    let token = "***"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, endURL, parameters: ["access_token" : token])
      .responseJSON { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
          for i in 0..<JSON.count {
            let titleA: String = String(JSON[i]["title"])
            let descA: String = String(JSON[i]["description"])
            let imgA: String = String(JSON[i]["images"])
            self.data += [Shot(title: titleA, desc: descA, img: imgA)]
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that after the function is performed, the array stays void. What's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question, rather than links to images of it; links can become invalid and images can't be easily copied into an editor for testing.

Comment: Another note: the init that you've defined in your Shot struct duplicates the default initializer that the struct type provides. You can delete that and still call Shot(title: "", desc: "", img: "") and it will work the same.

Comment: @geraldWilliam ok thanks

Comment: @CalebBrinkman You're right. Sorry but I'm new to Stack Overflow and I didn't know how to do that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working under the assumption that you've called this method as follows:

```
authDribbble()
print("my data: \(self.data)") // Prints empty array.
```

The issue is that Alamofire is performing the request asynchronously. That is, the work isn't done yet when your code proceeds to the next line (the print statement). You need to implement a callback mechanism. One way to do this is to pass a function as a parameter of your `authDribbble()` function. That would change the function to something like:

```
  func authDribbble(completion: () -> Void) {
    // create the url
    // create parameters
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url!, parameters: params)
      .responseJSON { response in

        guard let  JSON = response.result.value as? [[String : AnyObject]] else {
          // Wrong type in JSON response. 
          print(response.result.error)
        }
        self.data = JSON.map { dict in
          guard let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                     desc = dict["description"] as? String,
                      img = dict["images"] as? String else {
            // Handle error creating Shot from JSON
          }
          return Shot(title: title, desc: desc, img: img)
        }
        completion()

      }
    }
  }
```

You would then replace the call to `authDribbble()` with:

```
authDribbble() {
   print("data: \(self.data)") // Prints populated array.
}
```

Comment: You've been very exhausted, thanks. But there's a problem. I updated the code as you said, but it still doesn't print anything. Any idea?

Comment: Here is the code: [link](http://s16.postimg.org/en42awnph/Schermata_2015_11_14_alle_19_59_11.png)

Comment: Ha, whoops, you're right. I missed the most important part, invoking the completion closure! See the edit.